# Open AI gym environments don't render, don't show at all

Tags: python, openai-gym

So I wanted to try some reinforcement learning, I haven't coded anything for a while.
On Jupiter Notebooks when I run this code

```
import gym
env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0")
env.reset()

done = False
while not done:
    action = 2  # always go right!
    env.step(action)
    env.render()
```

it just tries to render it but can't, the hourglass on top of the window is showing but it never renders anything, I can't do anything from there.

Same with this code

```
import gym
env_name = "MountainCar-v0"
env = gym.make(env_name)

env.reset()

for _ in range(200)
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    env.step(action)
    env.render()
```

Both of these don't work neither on Jupiter notebooks nor Pycharm nor terminal.
I'm on Windows.
Couldn't find anything similar to this online.
Yes I'm **new** to this

Edit-
I did this

```
# Install latest stable version from PyPI
!pip install -U pysdl2

# Install latest development verion from GitHub
!pip install -U git+https://github.com/py-sdl/py-sdl2.git
```

and it now says **error: windlib not available**

I tried

```
!pip install windlib
```

but still can't fix the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an older version that supports your current version of Python.
I solved the problem using gym 0.17.3

```
pip install gym==0.17.3
```

and the code:

```
import gym

env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0")
state = env.reset()

done = False
while not done:
    action = 2  # always go right!
    env.step(action)
    print(new_state, render)
    env.render(mode="human")

env.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, install the correct gym library

```
pip install gym==0.17.3
```

Second, solve the openGl mis-match version issue,

```
pip install pyglet==1.5.11
```

Finally, install the patch version

```
pip install --user --upgrade git+http://github.com/pyglet/pyglet@pyglet-1.5-maintenance
```

Comment: This worked! But how to get it with latest version/